# Amazing city of Mumbai

Tags: grammar

We spent  last weekend in the amazing city of Mumbai.

vs

We spent  last weekend in the amazing city 'Mumbai'.

Is sentence 1 correct here?
I have seen people use the city of New York, but New York is a state by itself and New York city is its capital,but Mumbai is the capital of Maharastra and not a state by itself, so can we use 'of' here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  "The city of Xxx" is quite a common pattern, not limited to New York. For [example](http://www.applet-magic.com/delhi2.htm):

> The city of Delhi has been historically one of the most important cities of India.

It is often used when one wants to treat a named city as a common noun and modify it with adjectives. It can be used with other placenames: Towns, villages, countries

One special case is "The City of London" refers specifically to the financial district, inside the old city walls, not to the whole city.

However, it is correct and idiomatic say "I visited the amazing city of Mumbai.

Comment: thanks @James K. sorry, but I have one more query. Can I use of with the name of villages too /

Comment: edited...............